# Sub Navigation Bar with Hover Images

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, dreamweaver

I am creating a horizontal top navigation bar with images. I have the top bar ready to go (code below) but I am unsure of how to add the second and third level of navigation. For instance, when someone hovers over Business Essentials I would like the image itself to change to it's hover state, as well as display a table below it which is my sub-navigation. Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, but using images is the only way I can get the exact look requested. If anyone can tell me what my next step should be or give me a reference/example code it would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-   2);i+=3)
if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src;  x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
</head>


<body onload="MM_preloadImages('Nav2_hover.jpg','Nav3_hover.jpg','Nav4_hover.jpg','Nav5_hover.jpg','Nav6_hover.jpg','Nav7_hover.jpg','Nav8_hover.jpg','Nav9_hover.jpg')">

<table width="950" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="194"><img src="Nav1.jpg" width="194" height="67" alt="Home" longdesc="/home.aspx" /></td>
<td width="70"><a href="/bus_essentials.aspx" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('BusEssentials','','Nav2_hover.jpg',1)"><img src="Nav2.jpg" alt="Business Essentials" width="70" height="67" id="BusEssentials" /></a></td>
<td width="9"><img src="NavDiv.jpg" width="9" height="67" /></td>
<td width="68"><a href="/career_planning.aspx" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('CareerPlanning','','Nav3_hover.jpg',1)"><img src="Nav3.jpg" alt="Career Planning" width="68" height="67" id="CareerPlanning" /></a></td>
<td width="9"><img src="NavDiv.jpg" width="9" height="67" /></td>
<td width="108"><a href="/communications.aspx" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Communications','','Nav4_hover.jpg',1)"><img src="Nav4.jpg" alt="Communications" width="108" height="67" id="Communications" /></a></td>
<td width="9"><img src="NavDiv.jpg" width="9" height="67" /></td>
<td width="95"><a href="/ind_effectiveness.aspx" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('IndivEffectiveness','','Nav5_hover.jpg',1)"><img src="Nav5.jpg" alt="Individual Effectiveness" width="95" height="67" id="IndivEffectiveness" /></a></td>
<td width="9"><img src="NavDiv.jpg" width="9" height="67" /></td>
<td width="84"><a href="/leadership.aspx" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Leadership','','Nav6_hover.jpg',1)"><img src="Nav6.jpg" alt="Leadership" width="84" height="67" id="Leadership" /></a></td>
<td width="10"><img src="NavDiv.jpg" width="9" height="67" /></td>
<td width="77"><a href="/mentoring.aspx" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Mentoring','','Nav7_hover.jpg',1)"><img src="Nav7.jpg" alt="Mentoring" width="77" height="67" id="Mentoring" /></a></td>
<td width="182"><img src="NavDiv.jpg" width="9" height="67" /></td>
<td width="9"><a href="/effectiveness.aspx" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Effectiveness','','Nav8_hover.jpg',1)"><img src="Nav8.jpg" alt="Effectiveness" width="99" height="67" id="Effectiveness" /></a></td>
<td width="182"><img src="NavDiv.jpg" width="9" height="67" /></td>
<td width="17"><a href="/skills.aspx" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Skills','','Nav9_hover.jpg',1)"><img src="Nav9.jpg" alt="Skills" width="93" height="67" id="Skills" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I haven't seen the Dreamweaver generated menu in ages.. And you should not use it either. Just search for a nice semantic CSS menu

Answer (score 0):

There are about a million `jquery` scripts and tutorials out there that will do this without all the effort of attempting to hand code it. I don't know if this will work, but a quick google search came up with this:

http://www.webdesigndev.com/web-development/create-the-fanciest-dropdown-menu-you-ever-saw